# jQuery autocomplete method doesn't work properly

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, asp.net-core-mvc

I am trying to get a dropdown list using the jQuery autocomplete method, getting a list of data from an API but it seems to be off, any help would be appreciated.

the script:

```
   $(document).ready(function () {

        $('#autocomplete2').autocomplete({
            source: function (request,response) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '/Actions/AutoComplete',
                    method: 'POST',
                    data: $("#autoCompleteForm").serialize(),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    success: function (data) {
                        response(data)
                    },
                    error: function (error) {
                        alert(error);
                    }
                })
            }
        })
    });
```

the Action method:

```
[HttpPost]
    public async Task<string> AutoComplete(string input)
    {
        BadooBot bot = new BadooBot();
        return await bot.GetCities(input, "s1:379:TRRUJxhU0MNYtOiMOOlpKwL5StwQpkOmQFtSgmOV");
    }
```

The method that gets the information and returns it back:

```
     public async Task<string> GetCities(string input, string sessionId)
            {
                MediaTypeFormatter jsonFormatter = new JsonMediaTypeFormatter();
                HttpClient client = new HttpClient();

                var obj = JsonSerializerToObject.SerializeToObject("{\"version\":1,\"message_type\":29,\"message_id\":92,\"body\":[{\"message_type\":29,\"server_search_locations\":{\"with_countries\":false,\"query\":\"" + input + "\"}}],\"is_background\":false}");

                HttpContent content = new ObjectContent<LocationQueryModel>(obj, jsonFormatter);
                var request = new HttpRequestMessage
                {
                    RequestUri = new Uri("https://eu1.badoo.com/webapi.phtml?SERVER_SEARCH_LOCATIONS"),
                    Method = HttpMethod.Post,
                    Headers = { { "X-Session-id", "s1:134:ik5Ki4OhC0VfGpQZKjEyKMnfWfNr1aROyvPwZRYy" } },
                    Content = content

                };
                var res = await client.SendAsync(request);
                var locationResultModel = await res.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                var objRes = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<LocationResultModel>(locationResultModel);

                List<LocationModel> locationModel = new List<LocationModel>();
                foreach (var item in objRes.Body)
                {
                    if (item.ClientLocations.Locations != null)
                    {
                        var locationList = item.ClientLocations.Locations;
                        foreach (var singleLocation in locationList)
                        {
                            var tempModel = new LocationModel() { City = singleLocation.City.Name, Country = singleLocation.Country.Name, Region = singleLocation.Region.Name };
                            locationModel.Add(tempModel);
                        }
                    }
                }
                return JsonConvert.SerializeObject(locationModel);
            }
```

to make it easier to understand the method, he is making a call to an api service, retrieves the locations, then stores the locations in a List of locationModel and returning JSON.

everything works fine but when the dropdown appears its not working, here is a snapshot of how the input looks and the response that i get back :

[image]

and finaly the html itself for the input:

```
<form id="autoCompleteForm">
     <input id="autocomplete2" asp-for="input" type="text" >
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok I figured it out, funny that it takes me all day and only after I ask it here lol, the problem was I was trying to send a complex model , meaning the model had "country", "city", "region, so it couldn't use it, I used string builder to append all the fields to one string and only THEN add it to the list and then send that list.

the old list model:

```
{"LocationModel":[
  { "Country":"John"},
  { "City":"Anna"},
  { "Region":"Peter"}
]}
```

new list model:

```
{"LocationModel":"Country + City + Region"}
```

so now its a simple object and not a object with fields.
maybe there is a way to do it the way I wanted to but this worked for me if anyone had the same problem.